# Doctrine 2.1 find entity by unique field

Tags: orm, doctrine, unique

I want to find an entity by an unique (in this example the email) field.

```
User
id (int, pk)
email (string, not null, unique)
password (string, not null)
```

I know that there is `findBy` for repositories but since the email field is unique I don't want to use a repository as there always will be only one result.

Is this possible?

Comment: The `em->find()` function also calls the `find` method of EntityRepository, so `findOneBy` should not cost you much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done by using `findOneBy`